# DocuSign: How to prefill multiple text tabs with the same label in XML?

Tags: docusignapi

How do I preload tab values in a server template that has tabs that share the same values and tablabels?
I am having trouble sending values to templates that share the same tablabel.
On the forum I noticed that in JSON you add a \\* before the tablabel.  
         Is that still required?
         Is that required with XML?

None of these work if two or more tabs have the same tablabel. It all works if tablabels are unique.

```
                  <textTabs>
                    <text>
                      <tabLabel>\\*17</tabLabel>
                      <value>360</value>
                      <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                      <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                      <DocumentID>4</DocumentID>
                    </text>
                    <text>
                      <tabLabel>\\*17</tabLabel>
                      <value>360</value>
                      <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                      <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                      <DocumentID>4</DocumentID>
                    </text>
or
                  <textTabs>
                    <text>
                      <tabLabel>17</tabLabel>
                      <value>360</value>
                      <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                      <shared>True</shared>
                      <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                      <DocumentID>4</DocumentID>
                    </text>
                    <text>
                      <tabLabel>17</tabLabel>
                      <value>360</value>
                      <RecipientID>1</RecipientID>
                      <shared>True</shared>
                      <PageNumber>1</PageNumber>
                      <DocumentID>4</DocumentID>
                    </text>
```

Do I need to send only ONE or one for each duplicate tab?

Answer (score 6):

If you have multiple tags with the same label "17" you only need:

```
<textTabs>
   <text>
      <tabLabel>\\*17</tabLabel>
      <value>360</value>
   </text>
</textTabs>
```

The "\\*" notation causes the specified value to fill all tags with that label.

Comment: You are my hero right now. Is this documented anywhere? Anyways, this saved my bacon today. @EricTCouch, please mark as answer